# very high ram usage in google cloud VM (linux)

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kvm

I am running a virtual machine on google cloud platform with 20 cpu cores and 256gb of ram. As soon as i boot the machine, all the ram gets filled up (this always happens no matter how much ram or cpu cores i put in there). After some time passes or if i open some programs, the machine becomes slower or, eventually, non responsive.

The virtual machine is running kvm and has sub virtual machines running in there but even with those machines closed, the ram still gets filled up.

Looking at htop, i dont see any processes using a lot of ram. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

RAM usage is likely a red herring as Linux uses RAM as recoverable cache - when yoy do a "free" command it should show caches/buffers which is reclaimable by the OS.

Its not pissible to say what is causing yoyr slowdown without more information, but disk IO is often a cause, and often related to swap. +Yoy may want to reduce vm.swappiness and make sure your hist is not overprivisioning RAM.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c5f8ecf41d586f43d5f6bc6bebdb4b33  Screenshot of free -h , swap isnt being used... and the vast majority of the ram is being used